# Signalling NDK thread from Java

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

My app is written 99% in C with just some Java helper functions for things not available in the NDK. As a file chooser I'm using a ListActivity that I'm starting like this from the Java side:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, FileChooser.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

While this ListActivity is running, my NDK thread waits for the user to select a file and close the ListActivity using

```
ALooper_pollAll();
```

Whenever an event wakes up my NDK thread, I'm calling the Java side using JNI to check a flag that indicates whether the ListActivity is still open or has been closed by the user. In my ListActivity's onDestroy() method I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {    
    super.onDestroy();          
    if(isFinishing()) listActivityDone = true;      
}
```

Now my problem is that when the user presses the BACK button in the ListActivity, my NDK thread gets woken up correctly but unfortunately, onDestroy() is called *after* my NDK thread has been woken up, thus my NDK thread does not get the correct value of the flag "listActivityDone". When my NDK thread is woken up, "listActivityDone" is still FALSE because onDestroy() is called immediately after my NDK thread gets woken up.

So what I need to do to solve this problem is wake up the NDK thread once again after having set the flag "listActivityDone" to TRUE. Does anybody know how this can be achieved?

Of course, I could call a C function from Java and then call ALooper_wake() but I'm almost sure that there is a nicer version to wake up the NDK thread from the Java side. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can move your flag to the onPause, onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {    
    super.onPause();          
    if(isFinishing()) listActivityDone = true;      
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {    
    super.onResume();          
    if(!isFinishing()) listActivityDone = false;      
}
```

That way it is called earlier. You can also consider putting it in onStop, if the onPause is not applicable for your specific scenario

Comment: I thought about that but I don't want the flag to be set on PAUSE. It should only be set when the user presses the BACK button (or chooses an item of the ListActivity's listview).

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't notice the use of isFinishing() in onPause(). Didn't know that this can be used in onPause() as well. I'll try it out.

Comment: Ok, it works with onPause(), but not with onStop(). So it could serve as a workaround for the problem. Still, I'm wondering if there's a nicer solution for waking up the C side from the Java side...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just handle the `APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW` command to shut down properly?

Comment: I don't understand that. Isn't APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW a command that is handled on the C side? How should I be able to use this from the Java side? I want to wake up the event looper on the C side from Java...

Comment: Why do you need to wake up the C side from Java? It seems as if you want to wake it up when you the activity is being destroyed. That command should be happening when the window is destroyed. Is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: No, APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW is happening when my C activity's window is destroyed but that's not my question is about. I want to wake up the C side when the subactivity that is written in Java is destroyed (the ListActivity). After the ListActivity has been destroyed, the C side should grab the user's selection in the ListActivity and then continue running. That's why my C side (NativeActivity) needs to wait for the Java sub-activity (ListActivity) to finish because the C side cannot continue running before the Java sub-activity has quit because the C side depends on the result of the Java side.

Comment: I would edit your question to give a better visual of what exactly you are doing since its not very clear. It sounds as if NativeActivity starts ListActivity. If that's the case, it should start ListActivity using startActivityForResult and then in onActivityResult in your NativeActivity you should call into your C code with the selected path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you've understood everything correctly. But what do you suggest should the C code that I call in onActivityResult() actually do? Remember that the C code (in the NDK thread) is still running ALooper_poll() at that time. So the C code that is passed the selected path from Java (in the UI thread) would first have to call ALooper_wakeup() to break out of the ALooper_poll(). I'm not sure if this would work though, because Java calls into C from the UI thread and the ALooper_poll() function is executed by the NDK thread...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but you should be able to wake up the looper thread from another thread since in Java its used to handle messages queued up on one thread from another.